# Как найти тип шифрования и ключ, имея исходный текст и зашифрованный итог

Tags: безопасность, взлом

В какую сторону копать по этой задаче:
имеется изначальная строка: "test", потом она шифруется и на выходе получаю "qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M="

Как исходя из этого начать копать чем он шифруется?
Знаю, что там постоянный алгоритм/ключ и хочу его узнать

Comment: Вы уверены что это шифрование, а не какой-нибудь `SHA-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не шифрование. Это хеш SHA-1 строки `test` записанный в base64.

```
$ base64 -d <<<qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M= | xxd -p
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
$ echo -n test | sha1sum 
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3  -
```